# Only import TypeScript types, not the whole module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-only-import-export

I have a project that already includes the required JavaScript files. However, I am trying to move some code into TS and take advantage of it. There's a library that I use (sweetalert2) that has been installed and is in node_modules (though not actually used from that location).

All I want to do is somehow include it in my TS files so that I get the Intellisense and type checks. Not actually import the code. If I import the code it does a whole lot of stuff that I don't need or want.

I think I've tried every variation of tsconfig and references and I can't get it to work. There must be a way!

Is there a way to just just reference the types so that you can take advantage in TypeScript and it doesn't complain?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`import type()`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html) to import only types.

Comment: Super excited when I saw that - not sure how I didn't come across it! But now I get TS1362 - cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type' I was able to add //@ts-ignore above to remove the error and allow files to be generated. Wish this wasn't the case, though